# Like #top, load page from middle?

Tags: html

How can I reload the page from Middle, I have 5,6 links showing images and First Image is without a link. So when I click on below links, it always show the top image.

1. Register






2. Show

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is exceptionally difficult to understand... but if my **guess** is correct, you want to place an anchor (with a name) at the position where you want to scroll to.  For example:

```
<a name="mymiddle">...</a>
```

Then you can call your page thus, and this will scroll to that position:

```
mypage.htm#mymiddle
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer just because I have no idea how you understood that question.

Comment: Thanks @jerome, it's years of working with people who can't create specification documents correctly ;-)